# How to style a single element inside Material-ui autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have an array of movies in a Material-UI autocomplete, and I want to add my favorite movie- Office Space- to this array. Is there a way I can give this single movie custom styling so that it has text `color: primary`?

```
export default function Playground() {
  const favMovie = {title: "Office Space", year: 1999}
  top100Films.push(favMovie)

  const defaultProps = {
    options: top100Films,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.title
  };

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 300 }}>
      <Autocomplete
        {...defaultProps}
        id="select-on-focus"
        selectOnFocus
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="movies" margin="normal" />
        )}
        onChange={(e, movie) => {
          if (movie) {
            setMovies([...movies, movie.title]);
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  ...,
]
```

See also [my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-n-stuff-qymsq?file=/demo.js:1503-1690)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in *Autocomplete* component:

```
renderOption={(option) => {
  if (option.hasOwnProperty("color"))
    return <div style={{ color: option.color }}>{option.title}</div>;
  return <div>{option.title}</div>;
}}
```

And edit you data model like this:

```
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972, color: "red" },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 }
];
```

See also my forked [codeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-n-stuff-forked-o0vtt?file=/demo.js:1797-2024)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style` property to ListItemText.

```
<ListItemText style={movie.style} primary={movie} />
```

Update your `top100Films` array's items to something like:

```
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994, style: {color: 'red'}}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, but I'm looking to put style in the drop down menu, not the <List>